# Check if some code ever existed in git

Tags: git, gitk

I am debugging an app I am working on and noticed that some code is missing that should be there.  I am pretty sure that it existed at one point in time and was accidentally (or maybe purposefully) deleted a while ago. I want to know how I can search a commit history to see if the code ever existed.  When I ran the gitk command it brought up a GUI with a search function, but I found that the search only looked at commit messages and not the content of the commit.  How can I search for the missing code in version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the git log with the -S option which will look for a given string in all the commits.

> git log -Sfunction_name

Comment: Did you mean to type git log -S function_name? it looks like you missed a space.

Comment: use the text you need to look for instead of the "function_name". It doesn't include a space though.

Comment: This link might be helpful  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Comment: @TylerHilbert: `-Swhatever` and `-S whatever` mean the same thing in Git (the parsing of switches in Git is pretty complicated, sometimes you can omit spaces, sometimes it's `--foo=bar` or `--foo bar`, in a few cases `--foo` has acquired an *optional* `=bar` so there's no `--foo bar` form, and so on; so it's just a big mishmash of special cases, although there are general rules that *mostly* work.)